# Rest Web service parameter issue

Tags: java, rest

am using below code to test a basic web service. When am passing normal string it works fine for example - http://localhost.com:8080/CheckRest/rest/pmg?p1=xyz. It displays **HELLO xyz**

But when I add '#' to the URL it doesnt give the right output for example - http://localhost.com:8080/CheckRest/rest/pmg?p1=xyz#abc. It then displays **HELLO xyz** instead of **HELLO xyz#abc**

```
package com.check.ws;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/pmg")
public class CheckCall {

     @GET
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
      public String sayPlainTextHello() {
        return " ";
      }

      // This method is called if XML is request
      @GET
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
      public String sayXMLHello() {
        return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<pmg> </pmg>";
      }

      // This method is called if HTML is request
      @GET
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
      public String sayHtmlHello(@QueryParam("p1") String par1) {
        return "<html> <body> HELLO </body> </html>"+par1;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pound/hash sign (`#`) indicates the beginning of the [URL fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). If you want to use a pound/hash sign in your query string, you need to URL encode it by replacing it with `%23`:

http://localhost.com:8080/CheckRest/rest/pmg?p1=xyz%23abc

Comment: Is there any way I can run the URL with parameter as p1=xyz#abc and make some change at web service end?

Comment: You can get the fragment from the request and append it to your variable.